# Best way to Micro/split push with Phantom Lancer

Tags: dota-2

So, if you're playing with a bunch of minions (Don't know what the term is) [i.e. treants, spiderlings, phantoms] in DOTA 2 and you have 4-5 you want to push up one lane while you go somewhere else, what's the best way?  i.e. what if you want your guys to attack creeps on their way to a tower, right-clicking the tower they'll run past without stopping right?

I want specific mouse/keyboard clicks and such.  Any other tips on microing short-lived units is also useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the units you want to send down the lane, assign them to a control group by pressing control + 1-9 (optional), and press A followed by a left click. They will attack anything along the way to where you clicked.

Answer (score 3):

[Learn to use Dota 2's console](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHhchMKYSAE), and type `dota_player_multipler_orders 1`. All you need to do now is to create an army of your summons, hold down Ctrl, press A (Attack) and left click into their base. Then all of your units will attack towards that direction, and you simply recontrol the command of your hero.

This way you never have to worry about grouping your temporary summons, and it's handy to not loosing focus of your hero.

Comment: I do the ctrl click, and it's good, but it doesn't really work for split pushing if you get two groups of illusions going.  With the right click I am pretty sure I've had illusions run past a creep wave, which isn't what I was after.

Comment: A + Left click on the map. With 2 groups, mark half of them, issue command with Ctrl then issue command with selected.

Comment: Yeah, only habit I need to break then is ctrl-click which pulls them back.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put some more info in here, so I just added an answer.

- box-selecting and then a-clicking in between towers seems to be the best.  Possibly behind a barracks. I usually click on the mini map between towers or past racks seems to work best.
- With PL you need to re-select the new illusions after each wave and do the same, so the ctrl-group doesn't help much.
- Also, if you use ctrl-right-click for attacking illusions, you need to train yourself not to do it while split pushing. I could just turn it off, but it's super useful in team fights for focusing someone down, so I leave it on.